# Sphinx: Literal Blocks in class description causes overlap with Attributes/Methods table

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

Hi I have issue with Sphinx where my description text seems to overlap with the attributes and methods table. This happens when I add an indentation (Literal Block) to the class description. If my class description does not have any indentation, then the overlap issue does not happen. My expected behavior in the doc page is as follow:

Description,
Attributes Table,
Methods Table

but because of the indentation (literal block) I would get
Description
Attributes Table,
Methods Table,
Description (continued).

I've attached a screenshot for an example. Here in the screenshot, the list items are supposed to appear before the Attributes table:

- CHECK
- RETURN_HTTP_RESPONSE

[image]

Thanks for the help.

Edit:
The corresponding .rst file looks like so:

```
ProtectionRule
==============

.. currentmodule:: oci.waf.models

.. autoclass:: ProtectionRule
    :show-inheritance:
    :special-members: __init__
    :members:
    :undoc-members:
    :inherited-members:
```

Comment: Please include the reStructuredText source that generates the HTML.

Comment: In this bug report, you say that the Sphinx version is 1.8.3, which is quite old. Have you tried the latest version? https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/10246

Comment: I've added the corresponding .rst file. I have no tried a newer version of sphinx but that is something I can look into.

Comment: This appears to be about https://github.com/oracle/oci-python-sdk (source code for the class: https://github.com/oracle/oci-python-sdk/blob/master/src/oci/waf/models/protection_rule.py).

Comment: There is no literal block in the linked class definition, but the bullet list is malformed in the output (because of a missing blank line): https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/tools/python/2.60.0/api/waf/models/oci.waf.models.ProtectionRule.html

Comment: I've tried adding a blank line and that works if I only have a bullet list but if I have more paragraphs followed by additional bullet lists after, this overlapping will still occur.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].